# JQuery elements by tag name two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbytagname

I want a specific child of a specific element, I don't know how to do this.
I tried the following:
`$(document.getElementById(tableID).getElementsByTagName("th :a")).each(function(){`
`$(document.getElementById(tableID).getElementsByTagName("th").getElementsByTagName("a")).each(function(){`
`$(document.getElementById(tableID).getElementsByTagName("th a")).each(function(){`
`$(document.getElementById(tableID).getElementsByTagName("th").find("a")).each(function(){`

Is this even possible, or do I take it the wrong way?

Comment: it'll be good if you create a fiddle to show your problem

Comment: getElementsByTagName is not a function defined by jQuery.

`$(document.getElementById(tableID)` returns a jQuery Object.

Comment: that is neither jquery nor javascript. you should go for basic first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have incorrect selector to target anchor element. you can simply use:

```
$('#'+tableID+' th a').each(function(){
   //do something
});
```

Comment: You are very fast mate can't compete with you (: +1

Comment: can help if you can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.find()

```
$("#" + tableID).find("th").find("a").each(function() {...});
```

or

```
$("#" + tableID + " th a").each(function() {...});
```

In addition, you can use `.children()` to get the nodes which are just under the parent node.